# Python で 2 つの class を継承するとき、どこでどうやって super を書けば良いですか？

Tags: python

initializeでMiddleLayerとOutputlayerのクラスを継承？使用したいのですが、いまいちよくわからなくなってきてしまいました。
目標としては、initializeのコンストラクタで、MiddlelayerとOutputlayerの層数（50，3）と（3，50）を変更するようにしたいのですが、２つのクラスの継承だと、どこでどうやって、super...を書けば良いかわからないです。
プログラムは一応動きます。（クラスの部分は）

（あと、追加で実行して、OutputLayerのyを表示したいのですが、
最後の二行を実行したときに、

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'y'
```

がでてしまいます。

#### 追記

最後の二行の問題は改善しました）

```
class initialize(MiddleLayer,OutputLayer):
    
    def __init__(self,data_input,data_correct,number_continu,eta):
        self.input = data_input
        self.correct = data_correct
        self.m = MiddleLayer(50,3)
        self.o = OutputLayer(3,50,0.1)        
        self.number_continu = number_continu
        self.middle_affine = np.random.randn(1, 3)
        self.output = np.random.randn(50) 
        self.eta = eta
    def learning(self):
        for i in range(self.number_continu):
            self.m.forward(self.input.reshape(1,50))
            self.middle_affine = self.m.y
            self.o.forward(self.m.y)
            self.output = self.o.y.reshape(-1)
            self.o.backward(self.correct.reshape(1,50))
            self.m.backward(self.o.grad_x)
            self.m.update(self.eta)
            self.o.update(self.eta)
    
    def plot_sin(self):
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        data = self.output
        ax.plot(data)
        
        plt.show()

class MiddleLayer:
    def __init__(self, n_upper = 50, n =3,wb_width=0.1):
        self.w = wb_width * np.random.randn(n_upper, n)  # 重み（行列）
        self.b = wb_width * np.random.randn(n)  # バイアス（ベクトル）
    def forward(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.u = np.dot(x, self.w) + self.b
        self.y = np.maximum(0, self.u)
#        self.y = 1/(1+np.exp(-self.u))  # シグモイド関数
    def backward(self, grad_y):
        delta = grad_y * np.where(self.y <= 0, 0, 1)
#        delta = grad_y * (1-self.y)*self.y        
        self.grad_w = np.dot(self.x.T, delta)
        self.grad_b = np.sum(delta, axis=0)
        self.grad_x = np.dot(delta, self.w.T) 
    def update(self, eta):
        self.w -= eta * self.grad_w
        self.b -= eta * self.grad_b
    
        
        
        
# -- 出力層 --
class OutputLayer:
    def __init__(self, n_upper = 3, n =50,wb_width = 0.1):
        self.w = wb_width * np.random.randn(n_upper, n)  # 重み（行列）
        self.b = wb_width * np.random.randn(n)  # バイアス（ベクトル）
    def forward(self, x):
        self.x = x
        u = np.dot(x, self.w) + self.b
        self.y = u  # 恒等関数
    def backward(self, t):
        delta = self.y - t
        self.grad_w = np.dot(self.x.T, delta)
        self.grad_b = np.sum(delta, axis=0)
        self.grad_x = np.dot(delta, self.w.T) 
    def update(self, eta):
        self.w -= eta * self.grad_w
        self.b -= eta * self.grad_b

test = initialize(data_input,correct,1,0.1)
test.learning()
test.plot_sin()
```

Comment: 先ず`class initialize(MiddleLayer,OutputLayer):`の定義をMiddleLayer,OutputLayerの後に持っていけば良いのでは？ それから`test = initialize(data_input,correct,1,0.1)`の`data_input`や`correct`は何処に何時どのように定義/初期化されているのでしょう？ 質問記事のために何か削りすぎているような気がします。

Answer (score 2):

Pythonのクラスの多重継承については、@ITの[［Python入門］多重継承 (1/2)](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1908/27/news027.html) の記事が判りやすいと思います。

「２つのクラスの継承だと、どこでどうやって、super...を書けば良いかわからないです」という疑問については、superで指定するのではなく、親クラス名を指定します。

```
super.__init__(....)
```

だと、どちらのクラスの __init__が呼び出されるか判りません(少なくとも判りやすいコードではない)が、

```
MiddleLayer.__init__(....)
```

だと、 MiddleLayerクラスの__init__が呼び出されるのが明白です。

＝＝
多重継承で、複数の親クラスが同じ名前のメソッドを持つ(上記の__init__のように）場合に、どのクラスが優先されるかは、「C3線形化」というアルゴリズムで決められるそうです。